# Symfony2 switching validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have 2 customized input fields password and autoGeneratePw. **The validator should only validate password input when autoGeneratePw is unchecked.** How could I achieve this?

```
 $form->add('autoGeneratePw', 'checkbox', array(
            'label'=>'Auto generate password',
            'data' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
            ));
$form->add('password', 'repeated', array(
             'type' => 'password',
             'first_name' => 'Password',
             'second_name'=> 'RetypePassword',
             'invalid_message' => 'Password are not the same',
         ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Imho you're overthinking this. Just add the generated password in the required fields (and use a dummy field which won't be submitted to show it in cleartext to the user) like if it was entered from the user, this way you don't have to change anything (especially not the Form component). [Phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net/) does it like this for example:

[image: phpmyadmin password generation for a new user]

If you're afraid that the generated password wouldn't pass the validation, then you're doing it wrong. ;-)

Comment: users can choose between their own password or get a password from auto-generator. That why auto-generator is optional.

Comment: @rukabillaan See the attached picture from phpmyadmin. There's no need to reeinvent the wheel in a more complicated way imho.

Comment: you are right, I should not make thing more complicated. Thanks

Comment: @rukabillaan You're welcome. You could accept and/or upvote this answer if you deemed it helpful though… ;-)